# matplotlib plot ruined when changing size of x-axis

Tags: python, list, matplotlib

Suppose I want to plot a function as follows:

```
def f(t):
    return 1/(1-t)

def analytic_plot():
    t1 = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(t1, f(t1))
    plt.show()
```

This works fine. But suppose that for arguments sake, i want the x-axis not labled as `0-1` but `0-100`. In my mind it should be like this:

```
t2 = [x * 100 for x in t1]
```

But if we replot it now as:

```
plt.plot(t2, f(t1))
```

it doesn't at all do what I expect. Aren't we still mapping one element at a time from `t2` to the value of `f(t1)`?

Comment: What do you mean by ruined ? What happens?

Comment: The graphs doesn't look at all like it was prior to multiplying the x-axis by 100

Comment: Please clarify the before and after case. For me it seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the scope of your function. t1 inside the function is different from outside because you defined it different somewhere else.

Comment: @Rabinzel it seems to work now if I write it the way I did in my original post. I probably put them in a very odd order that somehow messed it up. t1 is only defined locally as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def f(t):
    return 1/(1-t)

def analytic_plot(x, y):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()

t1 = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
t2 = [x * 100 for x in t1]
y = f(t1)

analytic_plot(t1, y)
analytic_plot(t2, y)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have called the same parameters the second time around `plt.plot(t2, f(t1))`, to fix just change to `t2` in the first parameter:

```py
t1 = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
t2 = [x * 100 for x in t1]
plt.plot(t2, f(t1)) 
plt.show()
```

This will give you the following image (see the scale of x, 100):
[image: Img of the plot]
When using `plt.plot(t1, f(t1))` you are going to get the normal scale:
[image: Normal plot]

Comment: I want the exact same graph (same values on the y-axis) but I want the values on the x-axis to be 100 times larger.

Comment: @Randy is this what you are looking for graph wise?

Comment: yes, exactly, Rabinzel methods works although in my eyes I am doing the exact same thing?

Comment: @Randy Yes and no, like others already pointed out, you are not using parameters in the function. So what happened you probably called analytic_plot 2 times, but isn't changed. So the problem here is that we don't see the whole code what you did when you say "changed"